# Printing the values of a tuple

Tags: python

Accessing tuple values

How to access the value of a and b in the following

```
       >> t=[]
       >> t.append(("a" , 1))
       >> t.append(("b" , 2))
       >> print t[0][0]
        a
       >> print t[1][0] 
         b
```

How to print the values of a  and b

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you clarify what you mean by "the values of a and b"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do

```
print t[0][1]
print t[1][1]
```

But of course if you really want to look up for a or b, this is not the best construct, then you need a dict:

```
t = {}
t["a"] = 1
t["b"] = 2
print t["a"]
print t["b"]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler than expected:

```
>> t=[]
>> t.append(("a" , 1))
>> t.append(("b" , 2))
>> dict(t).get('a') 
# 1
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> t
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
>>> t[0][1]
1
>>> t[1][1]
2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print t[0][1]
print t[1][1]
```

??